# JavaScript: City name is not changing when end user inputs a new city

Tags: javascript

I am developing a weather app in JavaScript that is using the dark skys API.

The issue I am having is that when the end user inputs a city name (i.e. miami) and clicks search the city name does not change.

However, the current location of the end user does the load when the app is initially started.

I do not have a project server setup when I start the project I just fire up `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

Here is the JS:

```
console.log("meteocast.js, ready!");

// Global Variables
var geoLocation = {lat: 40.7127837, lng: -74.0059413};
var city = 'New York City';

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#selected-city').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
      ajaxReqForLatLon();
      setTimeout(function(){
        initMap(geoLocation);
      }, 500);
    }
  });
  // console.log(ajaxReqForLatLon);
  $('#search-button').on('click', function(){
    ajaxReqForLatLon();
  });
  $('.btn.btn-success.btn-block').on('click', function(){
    $('#selected-city').val("").focus();
  });

  // Traffic
  // Google Maps
  function ajaxReqForLatLon(){
    var userRequestedLocation = selectedCity();
    var googleApiURL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=';
    googleApiURL += userRequestedLocation;
    googleApiURL += '&key=AIzaSyCh5Q8_EFHuuQKVb4O3esOvemg-nFe6X0U';

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: googleApiURL,
      success: function(response){
        geoLocation = googleApiSuccessHandler(response);
        weatherData();
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
  }

  // take response from ajax and take the geolocation
  function googleApiSuccessHandler(response){
    var geoLocation = response.results[0].geometry.location;
    return geoLocation;
  }

  function selectedCity(){
    city = $('#selected-city').val().trim();
    if(city.length === 0){
      $('#selected-city').addClass('animated shake');
      $('#selected-city').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $('#selected-city').removeClass('animated shake');
      });
      return;
    };
    return city;
  }

  $('#selected-city').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
      ajaxReqForLatLon();
      setTimeout(function(){
        initMap(geoLocation);
      }, 500);
    }
  });

  // Map on page load
  setTimeout(function(){
    initMap(geoLocation);
  }, 500);

  var triggerOnce = true;
  function initMap(geoLocation){
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
      zoom: 12,
      center: geoLocation,
      scrollWheel: false
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map : map});

    if(triggerOnce){
      triggerOnce = false;

      if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
          geoLocation.lat = position.coords.latitude;
          geoLocation.lng = position.coords.longitude;
          var pos = {
            lat : position.coords.latitude,
            lng : position.coords.longitude
          };
          reverseGeocode();
          weatherData();
          setTimeout(function(){
            $(".location").html(city);
          }, 500);
          marker.setPosition(pos);
          map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function(){
          handleLocationError(true, marker, map.getCenter());
        });
      } else {
        handleLocationError(false, marker, map.getCenter());
      }
    }

    function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, marker, pos){
      marker.setPosition(pos);
      weatherData();
    }
    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    trafficLayer.setMap(map);
  }

  // Reverse Geocode 
  function reverseGeocode(){
    var googleRevGeoApiURL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=';
    googleRevGeoApiURL += geoLocation.lat + ',' + geoLocation.lng;
    googleRevGeoApiURL += '&key=AIzaSyCh5Q8_EFHuuQKVb4O3esOvemg-nFe6X0U';

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: googleRevGeoApiURL,
      success: function(response){
        city = response.results[0].address_components[2].long_name;
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
  }

  // Weather
  var weatherData = function(){
    var geoLocLat = geoLocation.lat;
    var geoLocLon = geoLocation.lng;
    var forecastURL = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/80b1dfb6da9003b42f0dd846a0f08703/' + geoLocLat + ',' + geoLocLon;
    var data;
    $.getJSON(forecastURL + '?callback=?', function(data){
      $('#weather').html('Today: ' + data.currently.summary + '<br>' + 'Currently: ' + data.currently.temperature.toFixed(0) + '&deg; F' + '<br>' + 'High: ' + data.daily.data[1].temperatureMax.toFixed(0) + '&deg; F');
    });
  };
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <input type="search" id="selected-city" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter City" autofocus>
  <button id="search-button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Search</button>
  <br>
  <h2 class="location"></h2>
  <h4 id="weather"></h4>
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: put console.logs or alert to debug flow  and value of your search box

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has something to with the button type being `submit`. You can try to change it to `button` instead.

Also do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: So it didn't work and sorry I forgot to mention there were no errors. Thank you for replying though! @Berkays

Answer (score 0):

You could try to modify some parts in your code

1. Change the type of search-button from **submit** to **button**. When
   user click button search, we will create an ajax request, so there
   is no need to submit page.
2. Update function googleApiSuccessHandler. In this function, add code to update city name.

```js
// take response from ajax and take the location information  
function googleApiSuccessHandler(response) {

    // Update latitude and longitute information
    var geoLocation = response.results[0].geometry.location;

    // Update city name
    city = response.results[0].address_components[2].long_name;
    $(".location").html(city);

    return geoLocation;
}
```

Comment: Okay. I will try this. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Hey @TrungDuong how's it going? I tried what you suggested, no luck but thanks for the suggestion.